# Vertical Align with table-cell Not Working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center my `header` element inside its parent element, but for some reason the `display:table-cell` method doesn't seem to work. I'm using [Basscss](http://www.basscss.com/) as a CSS framework, not sure if this has anything to do with it...

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.hero {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;

  header {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

I've set up a [CodePen over here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPbyry). For some reason, the `header` just won't center itself vertically.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `<header>` needs to have his direct parent element with a `display: table`.

In your CodePen, `.clearfix` and `.container` are on top of `<header>`. Also `.sm-col` has a `float:left;` property

See my edited [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNoQZp)

Comment: Is there a workaround for setting `.sm-col` to `float:none`, as this breaks Basscss's grid for the header element?

Comment: Here is a solution [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNoQZp), also there is a `.table-cell` class in BassCSS for centering content vertically ([documentation](http://www.basscss.com/docs/layout/#table-object))

Comment: Stupid me! Why do I always skim the docs. Thanks so much for finding this. And thanks for the alternate CodePen solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the entire header tag to the center, try using this code,

```
<header class="sm-col sm-col-12 center">
```

All I have done is just added the class center to your header tag which already had the sm-col and sm-col-12.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that for horizontally centering the text within the `header` element?

Comment: Yes, this aligns the header horizonatlly. For centring the header vertically, add a height attribute to the ".hero header" class. Please check the below link hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/Sha6m/8/